# c# dll generated pdf file is damaged

Tags: c#, pdf, dll, itext, class-library

I am using `iTextSharp` to write pdf file in c#.
I have created a `ClassLibrary` project and referenced in windows application.
the dll actually created a pdf file when called, but when I open the pdf file to view it says `There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.`

Here is my dll code to create pdf file

```
public class Class1
{
    public void CreatePDF()
    {
        // Orignal
        string filename = "Desktop\\TEST_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm") + ".pdf";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        doc.SetMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
        doc.Open();
        doc.NewPage();

        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED);

        iTextSharp.text.Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, BaseColor.BLACK);
        iTextSharp.text.Font fontSmall = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, BaseColor.BLACK);
        iTextSharp.text.Font fontBold = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 9, BaseColor.BLACK);

        Paragraph ClientName = new Paragraph("Client Name :" + " " + "Client", font);
        Paragraph Date = new Paragraph("Date :" + " " + DateTime.Today.ToShortTimeString(), font);


        doc.Add(ClientName);
        doc.Add(Date);

        LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
        ls.LineWidth = 7f;
        doc.Add(new Chunk(ls, font.IsBold()));

        Paragraph some= new Paragraph("Some Data", fontBold);

        doc.Add(some);

        doc.Add(new Chunk(ls, font.IsBold()));

        DmtxImageEncoder encoder = new DmtxImageEncoder();
        DmtxImageEncoderOptions options = new DmtxImageEncoderOptions();
        options.SizeIdx = DmtxSymbolSize.DmtxSymbol18x18;

        options.Scheme = DmtxScheme.DmtxSchemeC40;
        Bitmap qrbitmap = encoder.EncodeImage("123456789", options);

        iTextSharp.text.Image qrpic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(qrbitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        qrpic.ScalePercent(15f);

        doc.Add(qrpic);

        doc.Close();


        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
    }
}
```

and this is how I am calling it in windows application

```
Testdll.Class1 m = new Testdll.Class1();
        m.CreatePDF();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

it creates the pdf file but damaged. please let me know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix my code.

Comment: Do you have to generate the PDF - or are you able to work with word documents as well?  EDIT: Also in most cases iTextSharp allows you to make use of `using` statements to properly dispose of your objects.

Comment: yes because I have to generate a `QR Code` and text/csv file doen't support that.

Comment: I normally find it easier to write/generate the document in MS Word then convert to PDF.  Do you have an example of a finished document?

Comment: I was able to get a document generating (although with your current example it doesn't contain much to begin with).

The main issue I ran into was getting the `DmtxImageEncoder` (Which your OP didn't mention) to properly input an image (which I'm assuming is what you wanted for the QR code.

You were also doing a few things quite differently than the iTextSharp docs show.  

All in all it's more of a DmtxImageEncoder issue than an iText issue (although it can be improved on that front as well.

Comment: You didn't close your `writer` or your `fs`. As @confusedandamused already hints, `using` takes care of properly closing and disposing of resources.

Comment: @confusedandamused you are right, by comenting QR code I can see open the pdf, is there any issue with my QR Code? if yes then how can I improve it?

Comment: Please see posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things aside if you were to remove your current logic for creating QR codes - iTextSharp supports a few different types of QR/Barcode creation methods.

Aside from not making use of `using` statements the following code (along with your current code) will get you started with generating QR/Barcodes.  As I'm not sure what you want to populate the QR/Barcode with I'm unable to create an exact working copy for you, but this should get you off the ground!

If anything is unclear please let me know and I can edit my answer to provide a more clear understanding.

The below code is taken from the official [iText docs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-10#395-barcodes.java) (originally in Java), but I changed it slightly for your purposes.

```
          doc.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode PDF417"));
        BarcodePDF417 pdf417 = new BarcodePDF417();
        String text = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long "
            + "precisely --having little or no money in my purse, and nothing "
            + "particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about "
            + "a little and see the watery part of the world.";
        pdf417.SetText(text);
        Image img = pdf417.GetImage();
        img.ScalePercent(50, 50 * pdf417.YHeight);
        doc.Add(img);

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode Datamatrix"));
        BarcodeDatamatrix datamatrix = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
        datamatrix.Generate(text);
        img = datamatrix.CreateImage();
        doc.Add(img);

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode QRCode"));
        BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("Moby Dick by Herman Melville", 1, 1, null);
        img = qrcode.GetImage();
        doc.Add(img);
```

Below is an example of the output:

[image]